# Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to library class members. update the library version

Tags: android

I am trying enable proguard in my application but getting error like below how to find which library is need to be update please advice.

(http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
      (using '-keepattributes InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#libraryclass)
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
Note: there were 3009 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
      You don't need to keep library classes; they are already left unchanged.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#attributes)
      You should consider keeping the enclosing method attributes
Note: there were 301 library classes explicitly being kept.

```
    (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
Note: there were 1 classes trying to access enclosing methods using reflection.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
Note: there were 7 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
      (using '-keep').
:talabat:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug FAILED
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Comment: how u resolved this issue ?

Comment: I solved the all warning while doing the Pro guard. if you are using any third party libs please add the pro guard rules.Also make sure all google play services libs are updated to latest.